# Which of these "Safe" ECC curves are available in Bouncy Castle?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, asn.1, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to figure out [which "safe" ECC curves](http://safecurves.cr.yp.to/) are supported in Bouncy Castle.  I found a few curves in the namespace `Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1`, but they are hard to find, and I'm sure I'm missing some.

Do any of the following curves exist in Bouncy Castle? (should I use them?)

- M-221
- E-222
- Curve1174
- Curve25519
- E-382
- M-383
- Curve383187
- Curve41417
- Ed448-Goldilocks
- M-511
- E-521

Comment: Related http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15066/371

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an (apparently) [definitive list](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=362269) of the ECC curves supported by Bouncy Castle.  It seems to match the named curves defined in the [codebase](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.bouncycastle/com.springsource.org.bouncycastle.jce/1.39.0/org/bouncycastle/jce/ECNamedCurveTable.java).

None of the curve names match the names you listed.

However, there is nothing preventing you from tracking down<sup>1</sup> and using the parameters that define any of the curves you have listed to define an `ECParameterSpec` ... or a `ECNamedCurveParameterSpec`.

---

<sup>1 - The parameters are in the paper you linked to.  According to @mentalurg, it is not simple to get them into the correct form.  However, this is an open source project, so if >>you<< care about this, there is nothing preventing you from doing the work and submitting a patch.  Or if you don't have the time, sponsoring them to do the work for you.</sup>

Comment: Unless of course the mathematical definition is different from what is implemented in Bouncy.

Answer (score 4):

@Stephen C: "tracking down and using the parameters that define any of the curves" - wrong. The parameters (A and B) are only available for Weierstrass form. For Edwards or Mongomery forms one has to do a (error prone) coordinate transformation to Weierstrass  form, call the encryption, then transform results back to the original coordinate system.

Besides transformation errors, the performance for such transformed curve might be not optimal.

Both Java native implementation and Bouncy Castle are missing direct support of curve forms other than Weierstrass. And that is the problem.

Comment: The coordinate transformation itself is not error prone. It's the scalar multiplication in weierstrass form that's hard to implement -- losing most benefits of a "safe" curve.

Comment: Bouncy Castle is an open source project.  If you believe that support other forms of parameters / other curves is warranted ... it would be more constructive to code it yourself and send them a patch.  Or sponsor the project to implement it for you!

Comment: @Stephen C:   Sure. If you believe it is more constructive, just do that and pls let us know when it is ready.

Comment: @mentallurg - You seem to think that I care about this.  My advice is for someone who actually cares about this.  Someone who actually *wants* Bouncy Castle to implement those curves.  But certainly, whinging about it on StackOverflow is NOT going to get the "problem" fixed.

Answer (score 1):

BC as of today has the following list from FIPS-PUB 186-3. But 186-3 is obsolete now: https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/186/3/archive/2009-06-25)

```
static
{
    defineCurve("B-571", SECObjectIdentifiers.sect571r1);
    defineCurve("B-409", SECObjectIdentifiers.sect409r1);
    defineCurve("B-283", SECObjectIdentifiers.sect283r1);
    defineCurve("B-233", SECObjectIdentifiers.sect233r1);
    defineCurve("B-163", SECObjectIdentifiers.sect163r2);
    defineCurve("K-571", SECObjectIdentifiers.sect571k1);
    defineCurve("K-409", SECObjectIdentifiers.sect409k1);
    defineCurve("K-283", SECObjectIdentifiers.sect283k1);
    defineCurve("K-233", SECObjectIdentifiers.sect233k1);
    defineCurve("K-163", SECObjectIdentifiers.sect163k1);
    defineCurve("P-521", SECObjectIdentifiers.secp521r1);
    defineCurve("P-384", SECObjectIdentifiers.secp384r1);
    defineCurve("P-256", SECObjectIdentifiers.secp256r1);
    defineCurve("P-224", SECObjectIdentifiers.secp224r1);
    defineCurve("P-192", SECObjectIdentifiers.secp192r1);
}
```

There is another SP that lists the approved EC curves for key agreement: https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-56a/rev-3/final